# php ftp_get deletes local file on failure

Tags: php, ftp

Example:

```
ftp_get($ftp, 'movies.txt', 'MO'.date('md').'.txt', FTP_ASCII);
```

if `ftp_get` can't find a file `MO1115.txt` on remove server and the `movies.txt` file exists on local server, it ends up being deleted. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what i found on http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

*The zero size file is not a side effect.  When the ftp_get starts the first thing it does is to create the inode/file which it will stream the data too and that is a zero size file with the nname you specified for the local file.  When the download fails it leaves the file in place.*

So i would guess that the best way to handle this is to use a temp file and then check if it was written to or not. if yes copy if over the old file, if not simply remove the temp file

Comment: But the file is completely gone. It is NOT an empty file